# retrieve JSON array collection return from webhook c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following JSON that is received in my webAPI endpoint.

```
{"time":1507739203,"messages":{"closedChat":[{"id":1280091,"channel":"widget","closed_at":"2017-10-11 13:26:43","tabulation":false}]},"token":"5df3c296972ffa6972"}
```

I am able to get the "time" variable in my controller but I'm not able to get the "closedChat" collection, always returns null.

here is my controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/test1/closedChat")]
[HttpPost]
public string closedChat([FromBody] rag msg)
{
    string messageTime = msg.time; //this works
    List<Fimmsg> teste2 = msg.messages; //this do not

    return messageTime;
}
```

here is my rag class created to receive the JSON return:

```
public class rag
    {
        [JsonProperty("time")]
        public string time { get; set; } //this works

        [JsonProperty("messages")]
        public List<Fimmsg> messages { get; set; } //this do not

    }
```

and I created a Fimmsg class to hold the "messages" array/List:

```
public class Fimmsg
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string channel { get; set; }
        public string closed { get; set; }
        public string tabulation { get; set; }
}
```

What Am I missing to get the 'closedchat' collection?

Comment: `messages` is not a list, it's an object. `messages.closedChat` is a list.

Comment: Go to http://json2csharp.com/ and enter your JSON in and it will create the necessary classes for you.  Basically your issue is you have Messages as a collection but its actually an object that has a property which is the collection you are wanting.

Comment: thanks @CodeCaster, you are right it's an object, the answers I found were about deserializing an simple json, but not receiving it from a controller and sendong to a class that has this objct inside, but it shed some light on the problem.

Comment: thanks @Bearcat9425, your answer shed even more light showing how to create the classes correctly to receive the values :) thanks all!

Comment: updated the classes according to jspn2charp.com and were able to get the values :) I assume that the 'post your answer' is not available because it was marked as duplicate.. is that true?

Comment: Yes thats why, there are a large number of questions very similar to yours out there.